# publish windows application - ClickOnce Deployment

Tags: clickonce

Is it possible to publish windows form  C# application to a folder inside a web-dav server.
How can I achieve that..any help is highly appreciated.

ie want to  deploy Windows application, via a web page through ClickOnce (publishing using the publish tab in project properties in visual studio)

Comment: How do you mean publish? What do you expect to happen? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by Web-dav?

You can publish a windows forms app via a web page; you can even have it create the page.

Comment: happy to find your reply eschneider...I follow you in twitter.
You are right I was just trying install app via web-page.Now I could able to place my files in server as I mounted it locally .when I access http://mywebdavserver.com/application/index.html    .it downloads the Utility.application file .while triying to install a prompt comes - Cannot start appcn,appcn is missing required files..how can I solve this..do i need any server tweak for this..

Comment: Sounds like you are missing something on the target machine; .NET Framework, or some other dependencies.